# I am unable to connect my expo react native application with django websocket

Tags: django, react-native, websocket, expo, django-channels

```
useEffect(() => {
    const ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/awsc/');
    ws.onopen = (event) => {
      console.log(event.data)
      console.log('ws opened')
    };
    ws.onmessage = function (event) {
      console.log(event.data)
    };
    ws.onclose = function (event) {
      console.log("closed, code is:", event.code)
    };
    return () => ws.close();
  }, []);
```

The following code is unable to establish connection with django web-socket.
My django app is running on localhost and my react native app is running on expo app emulator

The following code is unable to establish connection with django web-socket.
My django app is running on localhost and my react native app is running on expo app emulator

I simply want to establish connection of my django websocket with my expo react native app

Comment: But are you able to connect to the django running on localhost with normal AJAX request?

Comment: Yes, I am able to connect it with vanilla JavaScript, ReactJs and I have tried connecting it with postman, everything is working fine, I am having issues only with react native

Comment: Though I use Laravel, I am also a React Native developer, I am not 100% sure if the React Native app will be able to connect to a server running on localhost, I would suggest you host the websocket on a live server, the last app I built I used websocket in the app for real time user chat using laravel and I hosted the laravel application on a live server and I connected the RN app to the live server throughout the development of the app and also connected to the websocket I setup on the live server to the app and it worked fine

Comment: Thank you man! I used django server through ngrok and it is working now.